# Install Laravel packages with Composer

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I have the problem to install the `Illiuminate/Html` package on my local machine into the exact folder of Laravel.

I am using Windows 7 and the Laravel version is 5.2.2. The path to Laravel is: `c:\xampp\htdocs\laravel`

In the `composer.json` I have added the package as following:

```
"require": {
      "php": ">=5.5.9",
      "laravel/framework": "5.2.*",
      "illuminate/html": "5.*"
}
```

When I run `composer update`, it installs the package, but not in the right place. The package is in: `C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\vendor\illuminate\html`

How can I specify the correct path?

Comment: What folder are you wanting it to end up in? That looks correct.

Comment: This package is installed at the right path

Comment: but all other packages are here: C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate

Comment: The `"illuminate/html": "5.*"` is no more a part of `Laravel` framework but a separate package of `Illuminate` so it's at the right place.

Comment: thanks, guys. Now it works :)